# CKM Matrix Magnitude Question - Top to Bottom Greater than One?

Tags: standard-model, quarks, unitarity

In the CKM Matrix article on Wikipedia, the "standard" parameters for each matrix element are written with combinations of sines, cosines, and a complex exponential of 4 angle values. Using the given formulas and the angles (I used the base value without including any of the uncertainty) and then finding their magnitudes gives these 9 values:

> [0.9734, 0.2254, 0.0415]
> [0.2259, 0.9742, 0.0035]
> [0.0402, 0.0111, 0.9991]

However, earlier, the article gives the magnitudes as:

> [0.9737, 0.2245, 0.00382]
> [0.221, 0.987, 0.041]
> [0.008, 0.0388, 1.1013]

Most of these differences can probably be attributed to the uncertainty which I left out (if not, I'd appreciate insight on the difference as well). However, the Vtb value given (1.1013) confused me. To my understanding, the magnitude of each term squared is the probability of that type of decay, and so the sum of the magnitudes of each column/row should be 1. How, then, can the Vtb value be greater than 1?

Comment: First, clean up your numbers by using the standard [pdg numbers](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/reviews/rpp2022-rev-ckm-matrix.pdf), specifically (12.15). Secondly, heed the caveat that the value fit to exceed 1 does not assume unitarity, and is, of course, compatible with it, within the stated error.